# How to mock ModelMapper in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to write unit test for my service layer:

```
@SpringBootTest
class ClinicServiceTest {

@Mock
private ProcedureRepository procedureRepository;
@InjectMocks
private ClinicService clinicService;

@Test
void setProcedureStatus() {
    when(procedureRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(initialEntity));
    when(procedureRepository.saveAndFlush(expectedEntity)).thenReturn(expectedEntity);
    Procedure assertProcedure = clinicService.setProcedureStatus(1L, "CANCELED");
  }
}
```

When i call `setProcedureStatus` method it throws NullPointerException because my service class uses ModelMapper that is being autowired by Spring:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ClinicService {

private final ProcedureRepository procedureRepository;
private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

public Procedure setProcedureStatus(Long procedureId, String status) {
    ...
    return modelMapper.map(procedureEntity, Procedure.class);
}
```

}

Unit test doesn't raise Spring context, that's the reason why ModelMapper is null in Service when i call it from test. Is there ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using SpringBoot? if yes try @SpringBootTest on class or use @ContextConfigurations(fullyQualifiedNames={ give here base pacakage name.*})    or did you try Mock them before using it?

Comment: Yes i use spring boot and i have that annotation on test class

Comment: Perhaps defining a @Before like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197442/junit-test-the-problem-when-converting-entity-to-dto-by-using-modelmapper-libra

Comment: @j1nma yes i've seen this topic, but when i try to put `any()` in ModelMapper, it doesn't work because of  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source cannot be null`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to write a unit test so you **shouldn't** raise the spring context. Unit tests are faster than Integration tests (where often you want to raise your spring context). When it comes to unit tests you want to test **unit** part of your application.

It this case you are getting NPE because you didn't initialize ModelMapper.

I didn't see where you are creating your ClinicService, but there is one example how you can avoid that NPE:

```
@Test
void setProcedureStatus() {
    when(procedureRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(initialEntity));
    when(procedureRepository.saveAndFlush(expectedEntity)).thenReturn(expectedEntity);
    // Initialize ClinicService with mocked procedeRepository but real ModelMapper
    ClinicService clinicService = new ClinicService(procedureRepository, new ModelMapper(), ... other dependencies );
    Procedure assertProcedure = clinicService.setProcedureStatus(1L, "CANCELED");
}
```

or you can mock ModelMapper too.

Another way is to use MockitoJunitRunner and initialize your class under tests like below:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class ExampleTest {
 
     @Mock
     private ModelMapper modelMapper;

     @Mock
     private Repository repository;

     @InjectMocks
     private ClinicService classUnderTest;
```

Thanks to dependency injection your code is much simplier to test because you can just create your service with dependencies passed via constructor.

Comment: Yes, first way really works, thank you. Second way looks much more pretty, but it doesn't work. Still NPE

Comment: @Alexey Iam not sure which version of mockito you are using. If you want use second version please paste your code and I will try to help you.

Answer (score 5):

If you are testing your modelmapper map returning values, you can use @Spy.
Example using:

this way is preparing a modelmapper with default constructor.

```
@Spy
ModelMapper modelMapper;
```

or you can customize with builder or constructor a modelmapper or any other types with instance creation way.

```
@Spy
ModelMapper modelMapper=new ModelMapper();
```

Therefore when you use a @InjectMocks they will inject inside the service or related field.